# Validating a List input in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, validation, sql-server-2005

Quick question about string validation.

We're implementing a stored procedure with a number of parameter inputs that filter its results. It's primarily going to sit behind an SSRS report.

We've set the proc up so that users can input either single values, or sql formatted lists (eg 'a','b',...) but our method for recognising a list is quite rudimentary. This -

```
if patindex('%''%'',%',) <> 0
```

ie we're checking if the there's a single instance of eg  `'item',`
We'd like to check lists are well formed beyond this - ie that the list is made up of a series of  `'item',`  blocks finishing with an  `'item'`  block, and with no stray commas between, an even number of apostrophes etc. If not we'd like to report back to the non-techie users rather than throw them an inscrutable error.

Any suggestions for doing this in TSQL? 
Or is this something SSRS is better positioned to do? (I confess I'm almost completely new to SSRS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a string split function in t-sql to split the entry into more manageable information. Then, use something like :

```
if (select count(1) 
      from dbo.StringSplit('''item1'', ''item2'', ''item3''', ',')
     where StringPart not like '''%''') > 0
...
```

Here is my personnal string split function, for your reference :

```
create function [dbo].[StringSplit] ( @p_String varchar(max), @p_Delimiter char(1) = ',' )
returns @ReturnTable table (
  [Index] int identity(1, 1) not null,
  [StringPart] varchar(4000) not null
) as
begin

   declare @EndPosition int
   declare @StartPosition int = 0;
   declare @TextPosition int = 1;
   declare @ChunkLength smallint
   declare @TemporaryString varchar(4000) = '';
   declare @LeftOverString varchar(4000) = '';
   declare @TemporaryValue varchar(4000) = '';

   while @TextPosition <= Len( @p_String )
   begin
      set @ChunkLength = 4000 - Len( @LeftOverString )
      set @TemporaryString = @LeftOverString + SubString( @p_String, @TextPosition, @ChunkLength )
      set @TextPosition = @TextPosition + @ChunkLength
      set @EndPosition = CharIndex( @p_Delimiter, @TemporaryString )
      while @EndPosition > 0
      begin
         insert @ReturnTable values ( LTrim( RTrim( SubString( @TemporaryString, @StartPosition + 1, @EndPosition - @StartPosition - 1 ) ) ) )
         set @StartPosition = @EndPosition
         set @EndPosition = CharIndex( @p_Delimiter, @TemporaryString, @StartPosition + 1 )
      end
      set @LeftOverString = Right( @TemporaryString, Len( @TemporaryString ) - @StartPosition )
   end

   insert @ReturnTable values ( LTrim( RTrim( @LeftOverString ) ) )

   return

end
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to reply. Thanks very much for this - it's a good approach and your help is very much appreciated.